# So what happened with Hats? Did we opt out?

Tags: discussion

I see hats are active on SO this morning. Were we skeptical that they would be well received here. Did some scientist come out in the press exclaiming that they would give us cancer (Source: Daily mail, obvs)?

What's the Straight Dope? (oops!)

Comment: We sent an opt-in message to SE, must be a mistake. I'll ask them about it

Comment: Hmm, now I see the Winter bash stuff (on the Skeptics man site), so it should work

Comment: Maybe I just dont have any hats over here. \*cries\*

Comment: Just go to the winter bash and see what actions cause you to earn a hat.  Have fun!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hats are enabled for Skeptics, at least I see the Winter Bash link in the top left and some hats on user profiles.

[image]

I'm not sure if you need to have at least one hat somewhere for this link to appear, though.